# RegEx get all characters before

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I have this regular expression to get urls:

`(((ht|f)tp(s?))://)?(www.|[a-zA-Z].)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.(com|edu|gov|mil|net|org|biz|info|name|museum|us|ca|uk)(:[0-9]+)(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9.\,\;\?\'\+&%\$#\=~_-]+))`

And I want to modify it so that when I call to make an array of the matched strings it will get everything before it as well.  How can I do this?

Comment: can you give a example for what should be matched. what do you mean with "when I call to make an array..."

Comment: This will not work for the majority of URLs in existence -- consider the other ~hundred country codes, IP-based URLs, URLs with non-ASCII characters, etc. See http://www.mattfarina.com/2009/01/08/rfc-3986-url-validation (first google result) for how tricky/impractical this is. Especially note all the holes and caveats mentioned in the comment thread. Similar to email addresses, I'm of the camp that validating URLs is a losing battle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepend ^(.*?) to the regular expression. That will set up a non-greedy match of all characters between the start of the input string and those matched by the rest of your expression.

Comment: It's quite possible that the pattern won't do what he wants, in the larger scheme of things, per Cory Petosky's comment above. As a rule, though, I try to give answers to the question asked. I hope that the answer will help Patrick and others learn more about regexes no matter the context. By all means, let's also discuss whether the question, or the implied approach to URL validation, is a worthwhile one. I agree that it's a tricky problem, and this particular regex doesn't handle international TLDs in a general fashion. However, that's easily fixed, and the pattern might be "good enough".